# How to get textchange event on Span

Tags: javascript

I am working with MVC3 Razor. There is one scenario where I need to change value of a DropdownList on Text Change Event on Span. But i do not find any text change event of Span.

Here is my code:
span id="lblSelectedShipperLotName">@shipperLotName

I am trying like:

But its not working. 
Thanks.

Comment: Apologies, but this makes no sense to me. I don't think change events fire on anything but form elements either. Surely a dropdownlist change event would fire to change a span, the inverse of what you're asking?

Comment: agree with above comment. how you will change value of span??

Answer (score 0):

maybe this work :

```
$('#lblSelectedShipperLotName').change(function(){
    alert('Hi');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it with a if/else?

```
  if ($("#your id").text != ("your text")) {
      // then do that
  } else if (ballal) {
      // your code
  } else {
      // your code
  }
```